# JQuery: Filter divs that do not match multiple attributes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to create a filter, that will only show divs that match two or more attributes. I currently have the below code, which works for selecting the position, but not for the language part.

```js
function ApplyFilter() {

  var Position = $('select.vacancy-position').val();
  var Language = $('select.vacancy-language').val();
  if (Position == 'choose') {
    $('.vacancies').find('.vacancy').filter(function() {
      return $(this).attr('data-vposition') != 'kies';
    }).fadeIn('fast');

  } else {

    $('.vacancies').find('.vacancy').filter(function() {
      return $(this).attr('data-vposition') != Position;
    }).fadeOut('fast');
    $('.vacancies').find('.vacancy').filter(function() {
      return $(this).attr('data-vposition') == Position && $(this).attr('data-vlanguage') == Language;
    }).fadeIn('fast');
  }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h2 class="">Search</h2>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label for="inputPosition">Function</label>
          <select id="inputPosition" class="form-control vacancy-position" onchange="return ApplyFilter();">
            <option selected value='choose'>Choose...</option>
            <option value='Mechanic'>Mechanic</option>
            <option value='Driver'>Driver</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label for="inputLanguage">Language</label>
          <select id="inputLanguage" class="form-control vacancy-language" onchange="return ApplyFilter();">
            <option selected value='choose'>Choose...</option>
            <option value='English'>English</option>
            <option value='German'>German</option>
            <option value='French'>French</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h3>Vacancies</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="vacancies">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col vacancy" data-vposition="Mechanic" data-vlanguage="Nederlands">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            Mechanic - German speaking
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            TEXT
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col vacancy" data-vposition="Mechanic" data-vlanguage="French">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            Mechanic - French speaking
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            TEXT
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col vacancy" data-vposition="Driver" data-vlanguage="German">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            Driver - German speaking
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            TEXT
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Could someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong and show me how to get this to work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should hide all of them first otherwise some *will* get left behind:  `$('.vacancies').find('.vacancy').hide()` - if you want to use .fadeOut then put the .fadeIn *inside* the .fadeOut complete[d] callback.   If you change the language, but not the position, then the old language entries will remain.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `filter()`  - [CSS Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) work just fine (along with the [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo class):

```js
function ApplyFilter() {

var Position = $('select.vacancy-position').val();
var Language = $('select.vacancy-language').val();
    if (Position == 'choose') {
        $('.vacancies').find('.vacancy').filter(function () {
        return $(this).attr('data-vposition') != 'kies';
        }).fadeIn('fast');
        
    } else {

        $('.vacancies').find(`.vacancy:not([data-vposition="${Position}"])`).fadeOut('fast');
        $('.vacancies').find(`.vacancy[data-vposition="${Position}"][data-vlanguage="${Language}"]`).fadeIn('fast');
    }

 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h2 class="">Search</h2>
            

            
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="inputPosition">Function</label>
                        <select id="inputPosition" class="form-control vacancy-position" onchange="return ApplyFilter();">
                            <option selected value='choose'>Choose...</option>
                            <option value='Mechanic'>Mechanic</option>
                            <option value='Driver'>Driver</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="inputLanguage">Language</label>
                        <select id="inputLanguage" class="form-control vacancy-language" onchange="return ApplyFilter();">
                            <option selected value='choose'>Choose...</option>
                            <option value='English'>English</option>
                            <option value='German'>German</option>
              <option value='French'>French</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            

            
        </div>
    </div>          

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h3>Vacancies</h3>
        </div>
    </div>          
    <div class="vacancies">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col vacancy" data-vposition="Mechanic" data-vlanguage="Nederlands">
            <div class="card" >
                <div class="card-header">
                    Mechanic - German speaking
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    TEXT
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col vacancy" data-vposition="Mechanic" data-vlanguage="French">
            <div class="card" >
                <div class="card-header">
                    Mechanic - French speaking
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    TEXT
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    



        <div class="col vacancy" data-vposition="Driver" data-vlanguage="German">
            <div class="card" >
                <div class="card-header">
                    Driver - German speaking
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
            TEXT
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>          
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Is it correct that if I now choose Mechanic as the function, and then choose German as the language, that both entries stay, German, as well as French speaking? Maybe I have not been clear, sorry for that, but what I would like it to do is that when I select a function, it should get all  vanacies for that function. If I then select a language, it should only show the, for example, Mechanic vacancies with that language requirement. It currently shows both mechanic vacancies dor both languages, even if I have selected German. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your show filter works just fine, but you got an issue with the hide filter, but i think you don't need that, just hide everything and only show what you want.

For that reason I upgraded the show filter a bit, also you had an error with one Language tag, it saied Nederlands instead of German.

```js
function ApplyFilter() {

  var Vacancies = $('.vacancies').find('.vacancy');
  var Position = $('select.vacancy-position').val();
  var Language = $('select.vacancy-language').val();
  
  if (Position == 'choose') {
    Vacancies.filter(function() {
      return $(this).attr('data-vposition') != 'kies';
    }).fadeIn('fast');
  } else {
    Vacancies.fadeOut('fast');
    
    Vacancies.filter(function() {
      const currentPosition = $(this).attr('data-vposition');
      const currentLanguage = $(this).attr('data-vlanguage');
      
      let pass = true;
      
      if (Position !== "choose" && currentPosition !== Position) {
        pass = false;
      }
      
      if (Language !== "choose" && currentLanguage !== Language) {
        pass = false;
      }
      
      return pass;
    }).fadeIn('fast');
  }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h2 class="">Search</h2>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label for="inputPosition">Function</label>
          <select id="inputPosition" class="form-control vacancy-position" onchange="return ApplyFilter();">
            <option selected value='choose'>Choose...</option>
            <option value='Mechanic'>Mechanic</option>
            <option value='Driver'>Driver</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label for="inputLanguage">Language</label>
          <select id="inputLanguage" class="form-control vacancy-language" onchange="return ApplyFilter();">
            <option selected value='choose'>Choose...</option>
            <option value='English'>English</option>
            <option value='German'>German</option>
            <option value='French'>French</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h3>Vacancies</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="vacancies">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col vacancy" data-vposition="Mechanic" data-vlanguage="German">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            Mechanic - German speaking
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            TEXT
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col vacancy" data-vposition="Mechanic" data-vlanguage="French">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            Mechanic - French speaking
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            TEXT
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col vacancy" data-vposition="Driver" data-vlanguage="German">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            Driver - German speaking
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            TEXT
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need `.filter()`, you can simply use an [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/):

```js
function ApplyFilter() {

var Position = $('select.vacancy-position').val();
var Language = $('select.vacancy-language').val();
    if (Position == 'choose') {
        $('.vacancies')
            .find('.vacancy:not([data-vposition="kies"])')
            .fadeIn('fast');
        
    } else {

        $('.vacancies')
           .find(`.vacancy:not([data-vposition="${Position}"])`)
           .fadeOut('fast');
        $('.vacancies')
           .find(`.vacancy[data-vposition="${Position}"][data-vlanguage="${Language}"]`)
           .fadeIn('fast');
    }

 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h2 class="">Search</h2>
            

            
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="inputPosition">Function</label>
                        <select id="inputPosition" class="form-control vacancy-position" onchange="return ApplyFilter();">
                            <option selected value='choose'>Choose...</option>
                            <option value='Mechanic'>Mechanic</option>
                            <option value='Driver'>Driver</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="inputLanguage">Language</label>
                        <select id="inputLanguage" class="form-control vacancy-language" onchange="return ApplyFilter();">
                            <option selected value='choose'>Choose...</option>
                            <option value='English'>English</option>
                            <option value='German'>German</option>
              <option value='French'>French</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            

            
        </div>
    </div>          

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h3>Vacancies</h3>
        </div>
    </div>          
    <div class="vacancies">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col vacancy" data-vposition="Mechanic" data-vlanguage="Nederlands">
            <div class="card" >
                <div class="card-header">
                    Mechanic - German speaking
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    TEXT
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col vacancy" data-vposition="Mechanic" data-vlanguage="French">
            <div class="card" >
                <div class="card-header">
                    Mechanic - French speaking
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    TEXT
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    



        <div class="col vacancy" data-vposition="Driver" data-vlanguage="German">
            <div class="card" >
                <div class="card-header">
                    Driver - German speaking
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
            TEXT
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>          
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Trying to see why you got a downvote - can only guess because your first =Position should be !=Position